# Trouble overriding template using a module

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.2

I'm trying to override the `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml` with a custom one but I can't get it to work.

The stock `address/edit.pthml` gets loaded in `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_address_form.xml`.

My custom customer_address_form.xml located at `/home/roy/www/dremelonline/web/vendor/activeants/magento2-checkoutchanges/src/view/frontend/layout/customer_address_form.xml` looks like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="customer_address_edit">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Roy_CheckoutChanges::edit.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

My custom edit.phtml file is located in `vendor/roy/magento2-checkoutchanges/src/view/frontend/templates/edit.phtml`

My module.xml looks as following:

```
<module name="Roy_CheckoutChanges" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        <module name="Roy_Base"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

I've flushed my cache and I have ran the upgrade command.

According to reading other posts about related problems, this code should work, but as you already know, it doesn't :p

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code into your custom module  `etc/module.xml`

```
<sequence>
       <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
</sequence>
```

**customer_address_form.xml** :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
          <block name="customer_address_edit">
               <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Roy_CheckoutChanges::edit.phtml</argument>
               </action>
           </block>
       </referenceContainer>
   </body>
```

Comment: It should be 'Magento_Customer` since I'm overriding the customer module right? Anyways, I already got `Magento_Checkout` and `Magento_Customer` in my sequence list!

Comment: yes, you should add module name which you want to override.

Comment: clear cache and flush

Comment: I forgot to mention that, I've already flushed my cache and I've ran the upgrade command.

Comment: check answer again.

Comment: I applied your changes and it didn't work yet, but then in the layout file I removed the element I wanted to override and created it again but with a different name and it worked!